# while text not in soup: - not picking up that text is in soup even though it exists

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

Writing a script to check if a product is loaded onto a website.

```
import requests
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('https://www.off---white.com/en/GB/section/new-arrivals.js')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
text = '3.0'

while text not in soup:
    print('not found')
    r = requests.get('https://www.off---white.com/en/GB/section/new-arrivals.js')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    time.sleep(5)
```

When I print soup I can see that '3.0' is in there. But when I run the script it does not recognize that '3.0' is there. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to check if the text is present in the source code, you don't need `BeautifulSoup`. You can directly check it using `requests`.

```
r = requests.get('https://www.off---white.com/en/GB/section/new-arrivals.js')
text = '3.0'

while text not in r.text:
    print('not found')
    r = requests.get('https://www.off---white.com/en/GB/section/new-arrivals.js')
    time.sleep(5)
```

If you need to use `BeautifulSoup` for any other reasons, you can use any one of the following:

- `while text not in soup.text`
- `while text not in soup.get_text()`
- `while text not in str(soup)`

---

Now, if you are curious as to why `while text not in soup` isn't working, read the following:

The *magic method* that defines the behaviour of `x in y` is [`__contains__(self, item)`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__contains__). If you look at the source code of `BeautifulSoup.__contains__`, it is given by:

> ```
> def __contains__(self, x):
>     return x in self.contents
> ```

So, by using `while text not in soup`, you are checking whether `text` is an item of list of elements (either `Tag` or `NavigableString`) returned by `.contents`. Since, `3.0` is some text inside a tag, it is not directly available in that list and hence `'3.0' in soup` returns `False`.

---

To check the source code, you can either go to the libraries installed on your PC and check the code, or use the following:

```
import inspect
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

print(inspect.getsource(BeautifulSoup.__contains__))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for such an informative answer - definitely learnt a lot here!

Answer (score 0):

Hi i have 3 things for you to try:

1: make sure soup is a string by doing:

```
while text not in str(soup):
```

2: try rearranging the while loop to:

```
while not text in soup:
```

3: if soup is an array and not a string you can do:

```
while soup.index(text) == -1:
```